# Flutter app becomes unresponsive when loading images in Gallery screen for the first time

Tags: android, flutter, image, dart, asynchronous

I have a Flutter app where I display a gallery of images in a GridView. The GalleryModel class is responsible for loading the images from the device's storage using the loadImagesFromDirectory() method. However, when I navigate to the Gallery screen for the first time, the app freezes for a short moment and becomes unresponsive. I suspect that this freeze is caused by the synchronous loading of all the images in the constructor of GalleryModel.

To resolve this issue and improve the user experience, I'm looking for suggestions on how to handle the asynchronous loading of images without freezing the app. I've considered using a FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder widget, but I'm not sure how to implement them in this context. Additionally, I'd appreciate any insights on potential causes of this issue and alternative solutions to improve the performance of my gallery.

gallery.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../widgets/image_container.dart';
import '../models/gallery_model.dart';

class Gallery extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: Consumer<GalleryModel>(
        builder: (context, galleryModel, _) {
          return GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              crossAxisCount: (width / 150).round(),
            ),
            itemCount: galleryModel.imageFiles.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final imageFile = galleryModel.imageFiles[index];
              return ImageContainer(
                imageSource: imageFile,
                borderRadius: 5,
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

gallery_model.dart:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class GalleryModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<File> _imageFiles = [];
  List<File> get imageFiles => _imageFiles;

  GalleryModel() {
    loadImagesFromDirectory();
  }

  Future<void> loadImagesFromDirectory() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    List<FileSystemEntity> files = directory.listSync();
    _imageFiles = files
        .where((file) {
          return file is File && file.path.endsWith('.jpg');
        })
        .map((file) => File(file.path))
        .toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> addImage(Uint8List imageData) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final imageFile = File('${directory.path}/${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg');
    await imageFile.writeAsBytes(imageData);

    _imageFiles.add(imageFile);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> deleteImage(File imageFile) async {
    await imageFile.delete();
    _imageFiles.remove(imageFile);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get all the images async and start a loading when loadimages call and hide the loading when image load done.

```
bool is loading = true;
notifyListener();

// fetchImages...

bool is loading = false;
notifyListener();
```

In the view you can check

```
Visibility(
   visible = isLoading
   // show loading
)

Visibility(
   visible = !isLoading
   // show images
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I followed your advice and added a isLoading variable and updated the function to get the images asynchronous like this:

List<FileSystemEntity> files = await directory.list().toList();

I also updated the gallery.dart accordingly (and also added a CircularLoadingSpinner).
While this approach did reduce the duration of the freeze, I still experience a brief pause at the beginning when navigating to the Gallery screen.

Comment: You should leave the isLoading to true always when user enter to your screen. don't make it true, when calling 'loadImagesFromDirectory' method. If still it freezes then I might suggest using Isolate or similar methods that do the processing in separate ( e.g Thread ).